# How to make mobs levitate?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map for my friends, and I want to create a 5x5 area where you see sheep go up then down over and over again. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Clue: [`minecraft:levitation`](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Levitation) Go figure out the rest yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to use `x,y,z` and `dx,dy,dz` arguments in your entity selector.
For example, if you want to target all entities in a 5x5 square, you can do
`/effect @e[x=0,y=64,z=0,dx=5,dz=5,type=sheep] levitation 10`.
This command will give levitation to all sheeps from `x=0,y=64,z=0` to `x=5,y=64,z=5`

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/effect give ...`

Answer (score 0):

`AreaEffectCloud` is your friend. `AreaEffectCloud` is a new entity used for lingering potions, you can summon it by `/summon area_effect_cloud ~ ~ ~ {Particle:"explode",Duration:9999999,Radius:5,Effect:[{Id:(effect ids),Duration:4,Amplifier:(any amount)}]}`

Answer (score -1):

The following command makes sheep levitate while next to you

`/execute @a ~ ~ ~ effect @e[type=sheep,distance=3] 1 1`

How this works is the “execute” command makes the command happen at all players(@a). The “effect” command is separate command attached to the execute command making effect happen where players are whenever a player gets within 3 blocks of a sheep the sheep will levitate.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute positioned as @a run effect give @e[type=sheep,distance=..3] letivation 1`